# How to go to import in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

Is there a shortcut in PyCharm to go to the place where a symbol is imported in current module?

I tried "Go To Declaration" but it goes to another module.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If you want to get rid of imports, you can always organize your imports.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: if this import was unused, I would not be able to use "Go To Declaration" on it. I just want to make sure that the  import statement just added by PyCharm is on its place.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: Another reason for this is to see from what module it is imported and change it.

Comment: I want to be able to do this to run the import statement in the terminal with Alt+Shift+e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer from JetBrains support:

> Try to use a shortcut for "Find Usages in current file": https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/finding-usages-in-the-current-file.html

---

> To find usages of a symbol in the current file
>
> 1. Click the desired symbol in the editor, or in the Structure view.
> 2. On the main menu, choose Edit | Find | Find Usages in File, or press <kbd>Ctrl+F7</kbd>. The encountered usage is highlighted in the editor.